# Count one word in different columns

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT agent, prezent, pobs, pobsextins 
FROM `raport` 
WHERE agent="agent1" and (pobs="da" || prezent="da" || pobsextins="da")
```

it returns:

```
agent   prezent pobs    pobsextins
agent1  NU      NU      DA
agent1  NU      NU      DA
agent1  NU      DA      DA
agent1  DA      NU      DA
```

What query must I write to automatically count the "DA" from all rows and group them by agent?

I have tried:

```
SELECT agent, prezent, pobs, pobsextins, COUNT(prezent), COUNT(pobs), COUNT(pobsextins) 
FROM `raport` 
WHERE agent="agent1" and (pobs="da" || prezent="da" || pobsextins="da")
```

but I found that it only counts how many times that column exists.
If I try `... COUNT(prezent) WHERE prezent="da", COUNT(pobs) WHERE...`
gives error

Comment: Can you share your desire output?

Comment: if is possible i want to see only `agent1: 6` and `agent2: 3` and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a sum on case and group by

```
select agent
      ,sum(case when prezent = 'DA' then 1 else 0 end ) + 
       sum(case when pobs = 'DA' then 1 else 0 end ) + 
       sum(case when pobsextins = 'DA' then 1 else 0 end )  total  
from my_table 
group by  agent
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use union all and group by.
I hope it should work for you.

```
select agent,count(*) from
 (select agent from `raport` where pobs="da"
  union all 
  select agent from `raport` where prezent="da"
  union all 
  select agent from `raport` where pobsextins="da") myReport
group by agent;
```

[Find the Output here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2d8786/33)

Comment: what error you are getting? Can you check now as I have modified it